# Magento 2: How to import csv to add more value to product attribute's dropdown options in admin?

Tags: magento-2.1, import, csv

I have created admin grid with layout and block now I need to know how to import CSV and use its value as array, for adding values I have written

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\OptionImport\Controller\Index;

class Mydummy extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_eavSetupFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_attributeFactory;
    protected $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attributeFactory
    ) {
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }



    public function execute()


    {
        echo "Hey Supriya";
        // an array of options which I want to add to attribute //
        $allStores = $this->_storeManager->getStores();
        $attribute_arr = ['Example1','Example2','Three'];

        //Load attribute by attribute code “manufacturer” to get attribute id //
        $attributeInfo=$this->_attributeFactory->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code',['eq'=>"manufacturer"])
            ->getFirstItem();
        $attribute_id = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
        $option=array();
        $option['attribute_id'] = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
        foreach($attribute_arr as $key=>$value){
            $option['value'][$value][0]=$value;

            foreach($allStores as $store){
                $option['value'][$value][$store->getId()] = $value;
            }
        }
   // add this option array to attribute
        $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create();
        $eavSetup->addAttributeOption($option);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Import product attribute options from CSV step by step explanation.
[image]

```
function addNewOptions( $object_Manager, $newOptions, $storeArray ) {

$option = array();
$eavConfig = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
$option['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getAttributeId();

foreach($newOptions as $key => $value){

    $option['value'][$value][0]=$value;

    foreach($storeArray as $storeKey => $store) {
        $option['value'][$value][$storeKey] = $value;
    }   
    echo 'Added value : '.$value.PHP_EOL;
}

$eavSetup = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup');
$eavSetup->addAttributeOption($option);
```

}

Comment: It's bad practice to use the object manager. Dependencies should be injected using DI instead